# how find Child using Tag

Tags: unity, c#

how find Child using Tag

so i have find this solution

```
enter code here foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        if (child != null && child.tag == "monster")
        {
            SpawnPoints.Add(child.transform);

            break; 
        }

    }
```

it add same child 1000 time how add 1 time

Comment: Why do you want to find the child using the tag? What game feature are you trying to serve this way?

Answer (score 2):

Global functions:

- Find one object with tag: [GameObject.FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)
- Find all objects with tag: [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)

Now, if you want to find an object with a tag that is also a child of a specific object you can use the following function:

```
Transform FindWithTag(Transform root, string tag)
{
    foreach (Transform t in root.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
    {
        if (t.CompareTag(tag)) return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: how i can put child in list          public Transform[] monsterOne;

Comment: monsterOne = root;          Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.Transform[]'

Comment: They are different types. The child will be in the project hierarchy, you need to call the method with the root of the hierarchy when searching for an object with a specific tag e.g. `FindWithTag(this.transform, "YourTag")`

Comment: Well I thank you for the reply but I get child as prefap So I don't understand how to put it on a list monsterOne

Comment: Perhaps update your question with more details, to get help on specifics.

Comment: Excuse me but am I unclear what I want to do?

Comment: @NADERLABBAD Iggy is recommending that you edit your question to tell us more about the game feature you're making. What is the game object we're doing this search from, and why do we need to gather its children with specific tags? Once we know more about why we're doing this, and how it relates to your game's features, we can probably offer you better solutions.